# Error 2 error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

Tags: c++

I am getting these errors

> Error 2   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
>   Error   2   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

my code is

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"

#ifndef uint32_t
#define unsigned int    uint32_t;
#endif

struct employee
{
    char        emp_name[20];
    uint32_t    emp_id;
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

what to do on this.

Thanks,
Ravindra Gupta

Comment: `_TCHAR` must be a macro, perhaps expanding to `unsigned char` or `unsigned short`.

Comment: I suggest that this is a better question than it initially appears to be. The problem is the `#define`, but the relationship between that and the error message is far from obvious; see my answer for details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually a rather interesting error; the error message doesn't do much to tell you what the problem is.

My initial speculation was largely incorrect, but I've left it in place for now. See below.

This code:

```
#ifndef uint32_t
#define unsigned int    uint32_t;
#endif
```

is incorrect.  The name of the macro being defined goes immediately after the `#define`, and a macro definition normally should not include a semicolon. (Macro definition syntax is quite different from declaration syntax.) Rather than defining `uint32_t`, this defines `unsigned`, and attempting to redefine a language keyword can cause serious problems. Also, the `#ifndef` is not useful, since the `uint32_t`, if it's defined via `"stdafx.h"`, is a typedef, not a macro. You can use `#ifdef UINT32_MAX` to check whether `uint32_t has been defined.  A correct version is:

```
#ifndef UINT32_MAX
#define uint32_t unsigned int
#endif
```

or, even better:

```
#ifndef UINT32_MAX
typedef unsigned int uint32_t;
#endif
```

That needs to be fixed, but it didn't cause the problem you're seeing.  Apparently `uint32_t` is not defined in your implementation, causing this declaration:

```
uint32_t    emp_id;
```

to fail.

The error message is still misleading. Since `uint32_t` has not been declared, it's treated as an ordinary identifier, not as a type name -- and type names are treated as *syntactically* distinct from ordinary identifiers. The compiler attempted to recover from the error by guessing that `uint32_t` might be a member name, which means it should be followed by a semicolon -- but then the declaration

```
uint32_t;
```

would declare a member with no explicit type. In old versions of C, this would be legal and would make the member an `int`. The compiler's guess about what the code actually meant was wrong.

Incidentally, if you show an error message, *please* tell us which line it applies to.

---

My initial speculation about the cause of the problem, which turned out to be incorrect follows. I had guessed that _TCHAR was a macro, but it's actually a `typedef`.

---

The macro definition:

```
#ifndef uint32_t
#define unsigned int    uint32_t;
#endif
```

has several levels of wrongness.  In a macro definition, the macro being defined goes first, followed by the sequence that it expands to -- which usually should *not* be terminated by a semicolon:

```
#define uint32_t unsigned int
```

But using a macro for this purpose is a bad idea; a `typedef` is much better:

```
typedef unsigned int uint32_t;
```

(note that the identifier being defined goes last, and a semicolon is required; macro definitions and `typedef`s have very different syntax).  And unlike macros, there's no way to test whether a `typedef` has already been defined.

The `uint32_t` should already be defined in `<stdint.h>` or `<cstdint>` -- but that's a standard header that was added to C by the 1999 ISO C standard, and adopted in C++ only by the 2011 ISO C++ standard, so there's a decent chance that it won't be available, depending on what C++ implementation you're using.  If the header exists, you can use `#ifdef UINT_MAX` to determine whether `uint32_t` is defined, but that's only useful if you're concerned about systems that don't have a 32-bit unsigned type at all.

But your code doesn't even refer to `uint32_t` -- so why did the macro definition cause a problem?

Because you got the order wrong, your macro definition doesn't define `uint32_t`, it defines `unsigned`, so that any occurrence of that word will expand to `int uint32_t;` (including the semicolon).

But you don't refer to `unsigned` either -- at least not directly.  The problem, then, is in your definition of `_tmain`:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
```

Both `_tmain` as the program entry point and the type name `_TCHAR` are Microsoft-specific. I don't have access to a Microsoft compiler at the moment, but judging by the error message you're seeing, `_TCHAR` (which logically *should* be a typedef) is probably a macro that expands to something like `unsigned short` (using a 16-bit type because Windows likes to use 16-bit wide characters for UTF-16).

So your definition:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
```

expands to:

```
int _tmain(int argc, unsigned short* argv[])
```

which, because you've unintentionally redefined `unsigned`, then expands to:

```
int _tmain(int argc,  int uint32_t; short* argv[])
```

And since parameter declarations are separated by commas, not by semicolons, this is a syntax error. I'm not sure why this leads to the particular error message you're seeing, but it's not terribly surprising. Syntax errors, particularly those involving incorrectly defined macros, often lead to confusing error messages.

The best strategy for something like this is *usually* to look at the *earliest* line on which the compiler reports an error. If the error message itself is not illuminating, ignore it and study the source, trying to figure out what you might have gotten wrong.

If that fails (as it would in this case), try running your program through just the preprocessor. Most Unix-based compilers, including gcc, use a `-E` option for this; I don't know the corresponding option for Microsoft. The output of the preprocessor is likely to be very verbose (it will include mangled copies of all the headers you include, directly or indirectly), but examining it might lead you to something useful.

In this particular case, commenting out your `#define` directive would have made the error go away (*CORRECTION: no, it wouldn't*), which would be a clue that there's something wrong with the `#define`, even though the relationship between it and the error message is far from obvious.

Answer (score 2):

```
#define unsigned int    uint32_t;
```

This causes `unsigned` to be a macro for `int uint32_t;`, which can't possibly be what you want.

Answer (score 1):

First off, `uint32_t` is usually a `typedef`, not a macro.  So, even if you have a definition in scope, your `#ifdef` will do the wrong thing.

Secondly, if you *did* want to make a macro named `uint32_t` (which I don't advise), the correct order is:

```
#define uint32_t unsigned int
```

**However**, you are *much* better off including either `<cstdint>` if you have it, or `<stdint.h>` to get a proper definition of `uint32_t`.  (I believe `<cstdint>` is C++11.)